# Why Apple Mail "Checking for Mail..." get lots of time?

Tags: mail.app, email

I used Apple Mail for few years and noticed that it became slower and slower through the time.

Currently I have two problems with it:

**1. "Checking for Mail..." which can last up to 10 minutes**

**2. When I selected arrived message "Loading...." could be shown for several minutes.**

I am using Apple Mail with my Google account. I have over 50000 messages in Inbox.

As for 1. I investigated what takes so many time for Apple Mail and found in Connection Doctor console that Apple Mail doing FETCH X-GM-LABELS for every message in my Inbox. Every time. Every day. Many times a day. Why?

Example:

```
* 46276 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS ("\\Important" "\\Inbox") UID 338150 MODSEQ (20634182) FLAGS (\Seen))
* 46277 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS ("\\Important" "\\Inbox") UID 338151 MODSEQ (20634123) FLAGS (\Seen))
* 46278 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS ("\\Important" "\\Inbox") UID 338152 MODSEQ (20634289) FLAGS (\Seen))
* 46279 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS ("\\Important" "\\Inbox") UID 338153 MODSEQ (20634418) FLAGS (\Seen))
* 46280 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS ("\\Important" "\\Inbox") UID 338154 MODSEQ (20634542) FLAGS (\Seen))
* 46281 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS ("\\Important" "\\Inbox") UID 338155 MODSEQ (20634680) FLAGS (\Seen))
* 46282 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS ("\\Important" "\\Inbox") UID 338156 MODSEQ (20634814) FLAGS (\Seen))
```

I also tried to delete and add account again. Same here. It doing this job every time I launch client.

I also tried to contact Apple Support. They switch me to Senior Advisor who told me absolutely irrelevant things like my Internet, or my VPN. I am not sure she even got my problem.

Is this okay for Mail client to do such useless things so many times and I need just quit using Apple Mail, remove it and forgot like a nightmare, or I am running into some kind of glitch every time with my Google account and it supposed to be cached at some point and can be fixed?

As per 2. Of course the first thing I done was disabling Mail Protection in settings. And of course that didn't helped.

Does anybody knows how can I just make it working? This is ridiculous mail client can't handle mail.

---

MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)

macOS 12.4 (21F79)

Apple Mail Version 16.0 (3696.100.31)

Comment: This isn't a structure I use, so guessing… but it's probably trying to sync every mail, every time. Have you tried archiving the oldest data, so it no longer has to actively sync the whole lot?

Comment: Good point. Will try. 

But again, archiving is a workaround for misbehavior of Apple Mail.

Comment: It's not really misbehaviour when it's having to sync 50,000 data points. This is actually one of the major failings of IMAP & one of many reasons I refuse to use it. I still use POP for everything, even if the underlying structure sits on IMAP.

Comment: Another problem is that Apple don't give me a choice.
Settings under "Server settings" in Mail allow me to set only SMTP server settings. Not switch IMAP to POP.

And also I believe that Mail should cache those X-GM-LABELS at some point. 
In the end they have "check new mail" and "synchronise mailbox" as two different options in menu. Both doing same according to connection doctor :)

Comment: I archived messages older than a year. Apple Mail still reading X-GM-LABLES for everything in my account. Every time :(